# Do I need to request Admin Permissions for Network Access?

Tags: java, windows, executable, uac

I have a java application wrapped in a [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) exe wrapper.

It serves web content on one user-configurable high-numbered port (default 8080).

It uses another network connection for data access.  This leverages TCP on unknown ports negotiated by an initial request on UDP 111.

I'm wondering if I need to configure this application such that it asks to run with administrator permissions, or if it should run with the permissions of the user who started it.

Comment: Do not run it with admin permissions. Ideally it would have it's own user and restricted permissions to only what it needs to be able to do.

Comment: @BevynQ in this particular instance, it's not running as a service.  The end user will start it up by clicking on a desktop icon and exit it when they are done.  My options are regular end user permissions or ask to be run as administrator.  If my end users require a special permissions policy for running software that accesses the network, I am happy to throw that into the system requirements, but I don't know windows policies enough to be able to say what exactly is needed.

Comment: user permissions should me sufficient for most applications. Also writing the application in such a way that a user can run it normally saves a lot of support grief.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, in general, you do not need to be an administrator to open a listening socket.

- The Windows Firewall might block incoming connections
- Java security itself might limit opening ports below 1024 (as .NET Windows Communication Foundation does)

But you do not need to be an administrator to open a listening socket.

And, as @BevynQ said, your application ideally won't be an administrator. Your TCP service will almost certainly have buffer overflows and security vulnerabilities. You don't want anyone on the network able to coerce your elevated application into doing bad things.

Comment: It has been forever since I asked this question, but I saw this again and wanted to pop in and say this is correct.  Once I went in and applied the policy that stated I did not need admin permissions, the prompt went away and the application continued to work perfectly.